# Calling Apache Camel RMI endpoint invoking method with multiple parameters

Tags: parameters, rmi, apache-camel, endpoint

Can I invoke Apache Camel RMI endpoint method that has multiple parameters?

The method signature that I call is:

```
public ReturnedVo methodSignature(String parm1, byte[] parm2)

Camel Route:
    from("timer:myTimer?period=5000".routeId("TestRoute").process(new Processor() {
       public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception{
          exchange.getOut().setBody(???????);
       }
    }).to (uri)
```

where `uri="rmi://serviceLocation?method=methodSignature"`

I was able to use similar routes to call different methods from the same service when methods had single parameter.  I was setting message body with instance of the object: `exchange.getOut().setBody(instanceOfObject)`.

The service that I am calling is remote EJB on Weblogic 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.  Here is what I have done to resolve the issue.

1)  Made changes to uri: uri="rmi://serviceLocation?
    `method=methodSignature&multiParameterArray=true`

2)  Create Object array to store parameters of the method to be called:

Object [] body = new Object[] {"parm1", new byte[11]};

3)  Changed camel route to use Object [] body:

```
from("timer:myTimer?period=5000").
   routeId("TestRoute").
   process(new Processor() { 
       public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception{ 
           exchange.getOut().setBody(body); 
       } 
   }).
   to (uri)
```

Please note that starting with Camel 2.9 there is different solution.  here is the link
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/bean-ejb-etc-how-to-set-parameters-td4375679.html